# How to extend the Worksheet class

Tags: python, oop, openpyxl

Hi would like to extend the Worksheet-class in `openpyxl`. However since this a second level container I am not sure how. Usually in openpyxl you instantiate with `wb = Workbook()` and then get an Excel-Worksheet with `ws = wb.active` or `wb.create_sheet()`. I am a bit confused here how to proceed. Of course you can do:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
class SheetExtended(Worksheet):
    def adjust_column_width(self):       
        for col in self.columns:
            max_length = 0
            column = col[0].column_letter
            for cell in col:
                if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                    max_length = len(str(cell.value))

            adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
            self.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

However I do I then incorperate that with the `Workbook`-class?

Comment: You say you want to add a class method, but `for col in cls.columns:` seems to suggest you want to loop over the actual columns of an actual instance of the class. So it seems you really don't want to add a class method, but a method to operate on an instance (with `self`) as the main argument?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. you are correct. I just edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can go about "monkey patching" `Worksheet`, so what you're doing works:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet


def adjust_column_width(self):
    for col in self.columns:
        max_length = 0
        column = col[0].column_letter
        for cell in col:
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(str(cell.value))

        adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
        self.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width


# monkey patching the new method onto the existing class
Worksheet.adjust_column_width = adjust_column_width


# an example of using it
wb = load_workbook('wb.xlsx')
wb.active.adjust_column_width()
wb.save('wb.xlsx')
```

If you would have needed a class method, you could have done this:

```
from types import MethodType


def some_class_method(cls):
    print(cls.__name__)


Worksheet.some_class_method = MethodType(some_class_method, Worksheet)
```

In general there's better ways to go about solving a problem than monkey patching classes though. Monkey patching adds behaviour that users of the class won't expect, especially since it still 'is' the original class, with no knowledge of its new functionality in the existing class.

The operation you're asking about could just as easily be a function that takes a `Worksheet` as an argument and modifies it, which would be a better solution. So the real question here is: why do you think modifying the class (or subclassing as you suggested) is the better solution? What is the use case?

Comment: One tiny disadvantage is that VS Code doesn't show documentation when you call e.g. `some_class_method`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Grismar for your answer. It pushed me in the right direction. The issue in this question is I didnt include the use-case in my question.

My use case is that I want to create one utility class which I can reuse multiple times to create my Excel-Files. I have several occasions where Excel-Files are generated and the logic for each generation is different.

Therefore I draw from [this great post](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#flexible-designs-with-composition) about the difference between Inheritance and Composition from RealPython. I have never consciously done a composition class, but given the dependency issues from `openpyxl` when you try inheritance I think it is the best solution.

It looks like this:

```
class ExcelGeneration:
    def __init__(self, workbook=None, sheetname=None) -> None:
        self.book = workbook if workbook else Workbook()
        self.sheet = self.__set_sheet_name(sheetname)
        
    def __set_sheet_name(self, sheetname):
        if sheetname and sheetname in self.book.worksheets:
            return self.book[sheetname]
        else:
            sheet = self.book.active
            sheet.title = sheetname
            return sheet
```

Issue with that approach is that you now always have to use `self.sheet` instead of `self`, however for my use case I am willing to pay that price.